# $A \subset X$ closed, $B \subset X$ closed. Prove that $A \times B$ is a closed subset of $X \times Y$.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Edit: I have been proven wrong.  Hence the claim below is true.  I will post an answer on this feed.  Thank you everyone who helped.

*Claim*: Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces, let $A \subset X$, be a closed set in $X$, and let $B \subset Y$ be a closed set in $Y$.  Prove that $A \times B$ is a closed subset of $X \times Y$ (in the product topology).

(This is a question from my homework.  My work is showing that the claim is false but I am not very confident in my topological abilities and cannot see that I am doing anything wrong.  Will someone who is experienced with this will let me know what I am doing wrong or tell me that I am right?)

*Proof*: $A$ is closed in $X$, thus $A^{c}$ is open in $X$.  Similary, $B^{c}$ is open in $Y$.  Thus, by definition, $A^{c} \times B^{c}$ is open in the product topology on $X \times Y$.  However,

$(X \times Y) - (A \times B) = (A \times B)^{c} = (A^{c} \times B^{c}) \cup (A^{c} \times B) \cup (A \times B^{c})$

is not open in $X \times Y$ (specifically the sets $A^{c} \times B$ and $A \times B^{c}$ are not open in the product topology).  Thus, $A \times B$ is *not* a closed subset of $X \times Y$. **!QED**

Edit: I have been proven wrong.  Hence the claim above is true.  I will post an answer on this feed.  Thank you everyone who helped.

Comment: One good way to test your proof is to put it to the test. Take $X=Y=\Bbb R$ and $A=B=[0,1]$. Or even simpler, $A=B=\{0\}$. Is $A\times B$ closed in $\Bbb R^2$? If the answer is positive, then your proof is wrong.

Comment: Doesn't your proof prove too much, namely, that the product of closed sets is ***never*** closed? I think you can find easy counterexamples to that in $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R.$ If you run your "proof" on that example, maybe you will see where your mistake is. (Are you concluding that $U\cup V\cup W$ is not open from the fact that $V$ and $W$ are not open? How does that work?)

Comment: ***Hint:*** $(X\times Y)-(A\times B)=(A^c\times Y)\cup(X\times B^c).$

Comment: ***Hint:*** $(0,3)=(0,2]\cup[1,3)$, but $(0,2]$ is not open and $[1,3)$ is not open. Does that prove that $(0,3)$ is not open?

Comment: OK.  So unions of "not open" sets does not necessarily mean that the union is "not open".  Thanks for your input.

Comment: @bof does the union on the right hand side cover $A^{c} \times B^{c}$?  It seems like $(X \times Y) - (A \times B) = (A^{c} \times Y) \cup (X \times B^{c}) \cup (A^{c} \times B^{c})$ unless the last term is redundant.

Comment: @Tim if $(x,y)$ is not in $A \times B$, $x \notin A$ or $y \notin B$ which covers the two options in the union.

Comment: The last term is redundant, because $A^c\times B^c\subseteq A^c\times Y$ and $A^c\times B^c\subseteq X\times B^c.$

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is closed in $X$, thus $A^{c}$ is open in $X$.  Similary, $B^{c}$ is open in $Y$.  Then $(X \times Y) - (A \times B) = (A^{c} \times Y) \cup (X \times B^{c})$ which is a union of open sets in the product topology on $X \times Y$.  Thus, $(A \times B)^{c}$ is open in $X \times Y$.  Hence, by definition, $A \times B$ is closed in $X \times Y$. $\hspace{1mm} \blacksquare$